# Getting text whether or not nested inside an extra element when parsing XML

Tags: python, xml, lxml

I want to create a text file (the txt file in the repo below) with lines of poetry that are in an XML file (the xml file in the repo) with each line enclosed in a "l" tag. The problem is, three of these lines have an annoying "milestone" element that causes my code (the py file) to ignore the line when writing to the new file. Can anyone help?

Specifically, I want something like:

```
<l><milestone ed="P" unit="Para"/>τίς τ᾽ ἄρ σφωε θεῶν ἔριδι ξυνέηκε μάχεσθαι;</l>
```

...to be treated the same way as if it were:

```
<l>τίς τ᾽ ἄρ σφωε θεῶν ἔριδι ξυνέηκε μάχεσθαι;</l>
```

---

The input files are taken from https://github.com/DLibatique/texts/tree/master/iliad

(I know the code is messy and there are many ways to DRY it and set up my repo structure better -- just trying to get the basic idea down first and then I can pretty it up later.)

Code:

```
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')

import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('iliad_1_1-32.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

file = open('iliad_1_1-32.txt','w')
for l in root.iter('l'):
    file.write(str(l.text) + "\n")
file.close()
```

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<text>
  <body>
    <div1 type="Book" n="1" org="uniform" sample="complete">
      <milestone ed="p" n="1" unit="card"/>
      <l><milestone ed="P" unit="para"/>μῆνιν ἄειδε θεὰ Πηληϊάδεω Ἀχιλῆος</l>
      <l>οὐλομένην, ἣ μυρί᾽ Ἀχαιοῖς ἄλγε᾽ ἔθηκε,</l>
      <l>πολλὰς δ᾽ ἰφθίμους ψυχὰς Ἄϊδι προΐαψεν</l>
      <l>ἡρώων, αὐτοὺς δὲ ἑλώρια τεῦχε κύνεσσιν</l>
      <l n="5">οἰωνοῖσί τε πᾶσι, Διὸς δ᾽ ἐτελείετο βουλή,</l>
      <l>ἐξ οὗ δὴ τὰ πρῶτα διαστήτην ἐρίσαντε</l>
      <l>Ἀτρεΐδης τε ἄναξ ἀνδρῶν καὶ δῖος Ἀχιλλεύς.</l>
      <l><milestone ed="P" unit="Para"/>τίς τ᾽ ἄρ σφωε θεῶν ἔριδι ξυνέηκε μάχεσθαι;</l>
      <l>Λητοῦς καὶ Διὸς υἱός: ὃ γὰρ βασιλῆϊ χολωθεὶς</l>
      <l n="10">νοῦσον ἀνὰ στρατὸν ὄρσε κακήν, ὀλέκοντο δὲ λαοί,</l>
      <l>οὕνεκα τὸν Χρύσην ἠτίμασεν ἀρητῆρα</l>
      <l>Ἀτρεΐδης: ὃ γὰρ ἦλθε θοὰς ἐπὶ νῆας Ἀχαιῶν</l>
      <l>λυσόμενός τε θύγατρα φέρων τ᾽ ἀπερείσι᾽ ἄποινα,</l>
      <l>στέμματ᾽ ἔχων ἐν χερσὶν ἑκηβόλου Ἀπόλλωνος</l>
      <l n="15">χρυσέῳ ἀνὰ σκήπτρῳ, καὶ λίσσετο πάντας Ἀχαιούς,</l>
      <l>Ἀτρεΐδα δὲ μάλιστα δύω, κοσμήτορε λαῶν:</l>
      <l>Ἀτρεΐδαι τε καὶ ἄλλοι ἐϋκνήμιδες Ἀχαιοί,</l>
      <l>ὑμῖν μὲν θεοὶ δοῖεν Ὀλύμπια δώματ᾽ ἔχοντες</l>
      <l>ἐκπέρσαι Πριάμοιο πόλιν, εὖ δ᾽ οἴκαδ᾽ ἱκέσθαι:</l>
      <l n="20">παῖδα δ᾽ ἐμοὶ λύσαιτε φίλην, τὰ δ᾽ ἄποινα δέχεσθαι,</l>
      <l>ἁζόμενοι Διὸς υἱὸν ἑκηβόλον Ἀπόλλωνα.</l>
      <l><milestone ed="P" unit="para"/>ἔνθ᾽ ἄλλοι μὲν πάντες ἐπευφήμησαν Ἀχαιοὶ</l>
      <l>ἀλλ᾽ οὐκ Ἀτρεΐδῃ Ἀγαμέμνονι ἥνδανε θυμῷ,</l>
      <l n="25">ἀλλὰ κακῶς ἀφίει, κρατερὸν δ᾽ ἐπὶ μῦθον ἔτελλε:</l>
      <l>μή σε γέρον κοίλῃσιν ἐγὼ παρὰ νηυσὶ κιχείω</l>
      <l>ἢ νῦν δηθύνοντ᾽ ἢ ὕστερον αὖτις ἰόντα,</l>
      <l>μή νύ τοι οὐ χραίσμῃ σκῆπτρον καὶ στέμμα θεοῖο:</l>
      <l>τὴν δ᾽ ἐγὼ οὐ λύσω: πρίν μιν καὶ γῆρας ἔπεισιν</l>
      <l n="30">ἡμετέρῳ ἐνὶ οἴκῳ ἐν Ἄργεϊ τηλόθι πάτρης</l>
      <l>ἱστὸν ἐποιχομένην καὶ ἐμὸν λέχος ἀντιόωσαν:</l>
      <l>ἀλλ᾽ ἴθι μή μ᾽ ἐρέθιζε σαώτερος ὥς κε νέηαι.</l>
    </div1>
  </body>
</text>
```

Comment: I took the liberty of running the XML through `xmlstarlet format`, to make its indentation accurately reflect its structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `itertext()` to iterate over all text fields, even those inside nested elements (or on the `tail` of an enclosed element, as here):

```
for l in root.iter('l'):
    file.write(''.join(l.itertext()) + "\n")
```

Comment: Many thanks, both for the helpful answer and for filling out my initial post. To be clear, calling join() with a text iterator as a parameter on an empty string fills the string with what the iterator returns? (Sorry if my terminology is incorrect, still quite new to the programming game.)